# Keep property name when marshalling from Object to Json in JAXb

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to convert an object into a JSON with JAXb.
The object itself was created from an XML.
 It works great, the only problem is that the name of a java-class property called "content" annotated with @XmlValue is renamend into "value". Here is what I mean:

Xml:

```
<outcome type="even" color="red">32</outcome>
```

Java Object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Outcome {

    private String color;
    private String content;
    private String type;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    @XmlValue
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

Marshalling the previously unmarshalled object

```
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlAsString);
        Outcome outcome= (Outcome) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        marshaller.marshal(outcome, sw);
```

This is the result I get after Marshall

```
"outcome" : {
    "color" : "red",
     "type" : "even",
     "value" : "32"
  }
```

As you can see the property "content" is translate, when marshalling, into "value".

Desired result

```
 "outcome" : {
    "color" : "red",
     "type" : "even",
     "content" : "32"
  }
```

Using Java8.

Can you please help?

Comment: I found a solution, it was reported in the Oracle documentation. I hope it may be of help to anyone stumbling upon this.

All you need to do is to add a property like this:
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_VALUE_WRAPPER, "content");

please see documentation for other properties:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/json.htm#TLADG769